# Python : Hypteropt - Function input

Tags: python, hyperparameters, hyperopt

Im trying to implemnt a multidimensional hypterparamter optimization. I have a function with many arguments but only 4 which have to be optimzized.

I wonder how i can pass this to hypteropt.

I thoughtg something like this should work in a test function:

```
from hyperopt import hp, fmin, tpe, Trials
def testFuntion(x,arg1='arg1',arg2='arg2',arg3='arg3'):
    print(arg1,arg2,arg3)
    #args1,arg2,arg3 = args
    return x[0]-x[1]-x[2]+x[3]

space = ((hp.uniform('a', 0.0, 1.0),hp.uniform('b', 0.0, 1.0),hp.uniform('c', 0.0, 1.0)),hp.uniform('d', 0.0, 1.0),'blub1','blub2','blub3')
trials = Trials()
best = fmin(testFuntion, space, algo=tpe.suggest, max_evals=100)
```

But the function is trying to compare my strings somehow and raises Error: **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'float'**

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you should take care of a few things here. The most basic one is that, if you look into your definition of `space` closely, the first three values (`a`, `b` and `c`) are actually enclosed in a 3-tuple. This is what causes your error, `x[0]` is that tuple and you can't subtract the float `x[1]` in any sensible way here.

To avoid this kind of issue, I would like to suggest that you help yourself with a better naming convention when mapping `space` for your function arguments. Also, the way I understand your setup, I think you should remove constants from your function signature, as this is somewhat confusing and bloats your search space unnecessarily. Here's a complete example of what you want:

```py
from hyperopt import hp, fmin, tpe, Trials

def test_function(x):
    arg1='arg1'
    arg2='arg2'
    arg3='arg3'
    return x[0]-x[1]-x[2]+x[3]

space = [
    hp.uniform('x0', 0.0, 1.0),
    hp.uniform('x1', 0.0, 1.0),
    hp.uniform('x2', 0.0, 1.0),
    hp.uniform('x3', 0.0, 1.0)
    ]
trials = Trials()
best = fmin(test_function, space, algo=tpe.suggest, max_evals=100, trials=tials)
```

P.s.: Use the `trials` you defined in `fmin`.

Edit: although I don't quite see the point, since you don't call your optimization function directly, here's how you pass in more parameters that don't get optimized:

```py
from hyperopt import hp, fmin, tpe, Trials

def test_function(x):
    # x[4] is 'foo'
    return x[0]-x[1]-x[2]+x[3]

space = [
    hp.uniform('x0', 0.0, 1.0),
    hp.uniform('x1', 0.0, 1.0),
    hp.uniform('x2', 0.0, 1.0),
    hp.uniform('x3', 0.0, 1.0),
    'foo'
    ]
trials = Trials()
best = fmin(test_function, space, algo=tpe.suggest, max_evals=100, trials=trials)
```

Comment: thanks for answering. What i need is pass arg1, arg2,arg3 to test function without defining them in the testfunction

Comment: I edited my answer, essentially what you did in your question.

Comment: and if the not to optimize parameter would be an numpy.array([1,2,3]) for example ?

Comment: look, I already answered your question twice. I'm happy to answer a new one as well, as a new question.